# Building Django modules (app) without a project

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Following the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/reusable-apps/) on modularizing my django code, I have been able to seprate out some applications. I have made packages for these application, which we successfully use across multiple projects.

Our boilerplate project directory looks somewhat like this (very much like in the tutorial):

```
boilerplate/ 
boilerplate/boilerplate/settings.py
boilerplate/boilerplate/....
boilerplate/user_profile/admin.py, models.py, etc.
```

Ideally, we just `pip install` the `user_profile` app and include in the projects settings and we are good to go.

However, anytime I have to update the application `user_profile`, I have to run it within a project and do the development.

**Is there a possible workflow that I can follow so that I can roughly do the development only on the `user_profile` app/module without having to set up the entire project.** I know that the pain point in setting up a project is barely a line or two, but in my case we use custom database settings (using MongoDB) and setting those things quickly means I've to change the settings on my machine (or environment) everytime I've to work on this project.

Answer (score 8):

A simple minimal example is to create a file manage.py with the following code

```
import sys

urlpatterns = []  
# since django will search for ROOT_URLCONF from settings,
# and we have given this same file as ROOT_URLCONF on settings, see below
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import django
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    settings.configure(
        SECRET_KEY='YOURSECRETKEY',
        DEBUG=True,
        ROOT_URLCONF='manage',
        INSTALLED_APPS=[
            # list of your apps
        ]
    )
    # Note: you may need to configure database also
    django.setup()  # setup django after configuring settings

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)  # let this handle commands as always
```

Configure the settings as you required ,and simply run 
- **python manage.py runserver** as an example